# What's the size of the smallest possible pixel size that can be physically detected using an electronic device?

Tags: optics, electronics

For a given wavelength $\lambda$, is there a limit on the size of the sensor pixel, regardless of the optical equipment attached to the sensor or the nature of the censor?

Comment: Thanks to the quantum mechanical nature of light deep-sub-wavelength optical system can be built quite successfully. The quantum efficiency of individual pixels in modern detectors is high, and as pixels are getting smaller, each pixel has to accumulate or count ever smaller numbers of photons (the total photon count rate is set by the total power of the incident light) which can, at least theoretically, be used to increase the dynamic range of the detector. Ideally each pixel would also record the wavelength and timing of the photon, which would allow for multispectral high speed imaging.

Comment: @CuriousOne: is there a limit on how deep sub-wavelength is theoretically attainable? Rayleigh limit probably doesn't apply because one theoretically can create a lens with arbitrary diameter. Still, can one squeeze a wave of length $\lambda$ into a pixel of size, say, $\lambda/100$?

Comment: One can take this to atomic resolution, below that there is no material to build optics from, of course. Look at it this way: single atoms can emit and absorb photons. That's the limit because nucleons do not respond to optical frequencies except under unrealizable magnetic fields (if you manage to make a local field of 1e10-1e11T, the game changes, again). So as long as you can devise techniques (like plasmon resonance) to make sever atoms or electrons on atomic distances in a metal to do something at the frequency of visible light (or IR), you have some form of "optics".

Comment: Although in theory one might be able to go down to atomic size, in practice, the limit will be reached at a much larger size.  This limit will be set by how small can a CMOS crystal be made and how "cleanly" can its small signal be amplified and separated from "noise."

Comment: Do you actually mean pixel size, or pixel spacing? There is a whole world of sub-wavelength optics out there, but to build a true "CMOS/CCD pixel" proper, you need enough silicon atoms in a volume of crystal to form a true band gap and depleted junction for the sensor, and the associated circuit for the pixel, and that puts a totally different constraint on the pixel spacing.

Comment: @uhoh: semiconductor industry is notorious for breaking every 3 years manufacturing barriers that were  considered unbreakable laws of Physics only 3 years ago. This has been going on since the dawn of Moore's law. It seems the only barriers we wouldn't break would be operational physical limits. Don't worry about needing "enough silicon atoms in a volume of crystal" for this or that technical purpose - things like that are being overcome all the time. The only limit I am interested in is the minimal size of area that is physically necessary to register a photon of a certain wavelength.

Comment: @Michael OK well I'm one of those people who's been doing that and I can guarantee you we never broke any laws of physics or ever even tried. The semiconductor industry has "enforced Mooer's Law" by embracing the laws of physics wholeheartedly (and making a lot of engineers miserable in the process!). Your title says CCD/CMOS pixel, and those are real names of actual things that we make. If you just want localized, single pixel detection, better remove those terms. This is a really interesting question and I just wanted to clarify the scope.

Comment: @uhoh, I am one of those engineers you were "making miserable in the process". :-) BTW, I didn't say the industry was breaking the laws of Physics, only that the industry was breaking the barriers that were considered the laws of Physics just a few years ago. Things like printing deeply sub-wavelength features, you know,

Comment: @Michael  yep yep :)

Answer (score 1):

For visible photons, I believe this is really a **quantum mechanical** question.  The absorption of light into a detector is a quantum phenomena.  It some way, it is the coupling of the frequency of light with a dipole in the atomic media.  That dipole moves with the frequency of the light and this coupling can cause absorption and photoelectrons to be formed as the excited electron decays.

From this viewpoint, they limit of absorption is based upon the coupling efficiency as a function of the confinement of the optical field.

This is not restricted to *quantum mechanics*.  One such classical dipole is your TV antenna.  It is much less than $\lambda$ in size, yet it *absorbs* RF photons.  Patch and coiled antennas have a lateral dimension even smaller than a wavelength.

Metamaterials have been made from split ring resonators which form capacitive and inductive features much smaller than $\lambda$.

Comment: A dipole antenna has a physical length which is slightly less than half a wavelength and acts as a resonant element.